# Skip empty inputFile in server function

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app that allows users to upload 2 - 4 files, with four different fileInput.

I am struggling with skipping the empty files, instead of getting an error message for the empty files in my function. I already tried to remove the "if(is.null(NULL))" change it to "if(is.null())" to do nothing for the third and fourth file, but still I get the same error message:

```
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 32, 0
```

Here my code:

UI:

```
                         fileInput('file1', 'Upload the data you want to test', 
                                   accept=c('text/csv', 
                                            'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                            '.csv')),
                         fileInput('file2', 'Upload your comparison data', 
                                   accept=c('text/csv', 
                                            'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                            '.csv')),
                         fileInput('file3', 'Upload your comparison data', 
                                   accept=c('text/csv', 
                                            'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                            '.csv')),
                         fileInput('file4', 'Upload your comparison data', 
                                   accept=c('text/csv', 
                                            'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                            '.csv')),
```

Server:

```
  filedata1 <- reactive({
infile1 <- input$file1
if (is.null(infile1)){
  return(NULL)      
}
read.csv(infile1$datapath, header=F, col.names = c('V1', 'V2'))
  })


filedata2 <- reactive({
infile2 <- input$file2
if (is.null(infile2)){
  return(NULL)      
}
read.csv(infile2$datapath, header=F, col.names = c('V1', 'V2'))
})


filedata3 <- reactive({
infile3 <- input$file3
if (is.null(infile3)){
  return()      
}
read.csv(infile3$datapath, header=F, col.names = c('V1', 'V2'))
})


filedata4 <- reactive({
infile4 <- input$file4
if (is.null(infile4)){
  return()      
}
read.csv(infile4$datapath, header=F, col.names = c('V1', 'V2'))
})
```

Here the function that calls all four files, also on the server:

```
 data <- zoo(cbind(filedata1(), filedata2(), filedata3(), filedata4()))
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Not sure why (I'd love to know more from someone more aknowledged) but this work: `data <- zoo(cbind2(filedata1(), filedata2(), filedata3(), filedata4()))`

Comment: Indeed that helped, thanks a lot! Not sure why either!